# How to use customisation provided in property observers?

Tags: swift, properties, observers

I pasted this code from Swift programming language PDF Property Chapter and I want to know How can I use the customisation provided in willSet and didSet 
I mean in what situation this code uses println provided in willSet and didSet and prints "about to set steps tp(newTotalSteps)" or the other one ...?

```
class StepCounter {
    var totalSteps:Int=0
        {
            willSet(newTotalSteps){
                println("about to set total steps to\(newTotalSteps)")
            }
        didSet{
            if totalSteps>oldValue
            {
                println("Added\(totalSteps-oldValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}
let stepcounter=StepCounter()
stepcounter.totalSteps=200
stepcounter.totalSteps=360
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a playground. Copy & Paste your code in. Then on right panel, click the + and you can see the console output, play it.

[image]